# display multiple rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, asp.net-mvc-2

I've data (3 variables) to fetch from ms access database (Product table) and to display it on aspx page. I've managed to display only first row of data. Seems that problem is in aspx page code in foreach loop. I just can't get my head round.

Here is ProductController class:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string str = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\vindom\\Desktop\\DB2.accdb";
        //  connection string from database Properties
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(str);
        OleDbCommand cmd;
        OleDbDataReader reader;
        con.Open();
        {
            cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM product", con);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
                {
                ViewData["Prod_Type"] =  reader.GetValue(0);
                ViewData["Prod_N"] = reader.GetValue(1);
                ViewData["Prod_d"] = reader.GetValue(2);
                }
            con.Close();


        return View();
    }
    }
```

And here is the aspx code:

```
  <table>
  <tr>
  <th>Product Type</th>
  <th>Product Number</th>
  <th>Product Details</th>
  <th></th>
  </tr>
  <%@foreach (var item  in View)
  {%>
 <tr>
 <td><%= Html.Encode(ViewData["Prod_Type"]) %></td>
 <td><%= Html.Encode(ViewData["Prod_N"]) %></td>
 <td><%= Html.Encode(ViewData["Prod_d"]) %></td>
 </tr>
 <%}%>
 </table>
```

..and Product.cs

```
namespace Tok.Models
{
    public class Product 
    {
        public string Product_Type { get; set; }
        public string Product_NUM { get; set; }
        public string Product_desc { get; set; }

        public  ICollection<Process> Processes;
    }

    public class Process
    {
        public string ProcessId { get; set; }
        public string Process_desc { get; set; }
        public string Next_processs { get; set; }

        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the approach below.
This will iterate through your recordset, but what you have in your view will not work. You need to store your rows in some form of collection, ViewData["Prod_XXX"] is for single instances of data, not multiple rows.

You could build a list of rows like this:

```
List<Prod> prodRows = new List<Prod>();
while (reader.Read())
{
     prodRows.Add(new Prod 
     { 
         Prod_Type = reader.GetValue(0),
         Prod_N = reader.GetValue(1),
         Prod_d = reader.GetValue(2)
      });
 }
```

where Prod is a class defined thus:

```
 public class Prod
 {
     public string Prod_Type { get; set; }
     public string Prod_N { get; set; }
     public string Prod_d { get; set; }
 }
```

Then in your View you could have something like this:

```
@model List<Prod>
@foreach(var row in Model)
{
  //Your display HTML
}
```

This is not an exact answer, but I hope it helps.

Comment: I think that the reader.MoveNext() will result in a row being skipped, since `reader.Read()` will read the next row.

Comment: Well spotted Ann - the last time I used ADO was back with VB6 around 10 years ago, and you used to while(!reader.EOF){ //do stuff reader.MoveNext()}

Comment: At this point you're skipping rows because of both `.Read()` and `.MoveNext()`. Please remove the `.MoveNext()` as it is 100% unnecessary in this answer. Other than that, this is the right answer. Do that, and you'll get one more vote at least.

Comment: Thanks @Joshua, I updated my answer with your recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that, from the look of things, you're executing this code:

```
ViewData["Prod_Type"] =  reader.GetValue(0);
ViewData["Prod_N"] = reader.GetValue(1);
ViewData["Prod_d"] = reader.GetValue(2);
```

... three times, but each time you overwrite the previous set of values.

You also don't appear to be passing a Model to your view.  Since you want to iterate through a list of data, you need to define a class to represent the model record (probably `Product` or something similar), and pass to your view a collection of `Product` records that you have built.

Something like this (assuming you have a `Product` class):

```
List<Product> model = new List<Product>();
while(reader.Read())
{
  Product newEntry = new Product() { 
     Prod_Type = reader.GetValue(0),   // I'm ignoring the need to cast the values 
     Prod_N = reader.GetValue(1),
     Prod_d = reader.GetValue(2)
  };
  model.Add(newEntry);
}
// housekeeping
return View(model);
```

Comment: Yes I have a Product class.. Sorry should have mentioned that... Here:

Comment: I'm getting error on aspx page line <% @foreach (var item in model) {%>.... It says the server block is not well formed

Comment: Why are you using the <% %> syntax notation?  I'm less familiar with MVC 2 than MVC 3, but I wouldn't think you'd need that.

Comment: Well....If I don't use them it prints out foreach statement on the webpage... I'm dealing with mvc for the first time so I'd say I'm less familiar with both of them..)))

Comment: Does MVC 2 use the Razor syntax, or the older syntax (not sure of its name)

Comment: Doesnt look like...I know MVC 3 does, but not the second one

Comment: Then maybe the problem is the "@foreach".  Maybe it should be "foreach".  Just a guess.